# Create author-like addition to Rmarkdown heading

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am using `Rmarkdown` to create a `.docx` file.

I would like to specify the Word style used for a bit of text. Usually it defaults to `First Paragraph` (not sure why), but I would like it to default to `Normal` and have the option of choosing one of the other built-in styles (e.g. `Compact` or `Body Text`).

**Header:**

```
---
title: "Report title"

output: 
  word_document:
    toc: yes
    reference_docx: "SMC-Style.docx"
---
```

I have set up the `SMC-Style.docx` as a template and formatted all the styles as I desire. I just don't know how to make specific sections of text use those styles. I can get Heading 1-6 (using `#`, `##` etc), but not sure how to do the same for other styles, e.g. `Body Text`.

**What I have tried:**

I have tried to reproduce the examples [here](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#custom-styles) but none have worked

1. `[Test1 - this is 'First Paragraph' style]`
2. `[Test2 - Still 'First Paragraph' style]{#Normal}`
3. `[Test3 - Still 'First Paragraph' style]{custom-style = #Normal}`
4. 

```
::: {#Normal}
Test5 - Still 'First Paragraph' style
:::
```

5. ```
   ::: {custom-style = #Normal}
   Test4 - Still 'First Paragraph' style
   :::
   ```

Nothing seems to change the style associated with these bits of texts. Can anyone help?

**Session Info:**

R version 3.6.1, RStudio version 1.1.456 and rmarkdown v1.18, outputting to Word in Office 2013.

Comment: The examples in the manual quote the name of the style: `[Get out]{custom-style="Emphatically"}`, so it looks like you that may help (they also have no spaces around `=` but I'm not sure if that's important)

Comment: Tried adding quotes, and removing spaces. Didn't update the style :(

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue with your yaml header, try editing your header to this

```
toc: true
reference_docx: SMC-Style.docx
```

Comment: the table of contents is working fine, but I'll give this a go